# Canvas drawImage, scale out to show entire image

Tags: html5-canvas

I have an HTML Canvas element that I'm trying to fill up with an image. It seems to just show a very small piece zoomed, instead of the entire image.

I try to get the canvas and image's size, then use the optional arguments for drawImage as is below

```
  const canvas = canvases.first.nativeElement; // the nativeElement
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var background = new Image();
  background.src = irImageUrl;

  background.onload = (x) => {
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0,background.width,background.height,0,0,canvas.offsetWidth,canvas.offsetHeight);
```

I've verified via console.log the height/width is as follows

> background = 768/768, canvas = 960/678

I'm trying to make the image (768x768) fill up one full axis and auto set the other so that the aspect ratio is maintained and you can see the entire image.

How do I need to modify the drawImage params to do this?

Thanks in advance!

---

Obscure's answer below helped me most of the way, and I also had other issues. The canvas element was set to height/width 100% which caused the zoomed in confusion and it was in a parent element with variable size.

So now before I draw anything I set the canvas to its parents size and then Obscure's scaling works great

**My new and working code is as follows**

```
    const leftPane = this.leftPane.last.nativeElement;
    canvas.width = leftPane.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = leftPane.offsetHeight;

    let scale = Math.min(canvas.width / background.width, canvas.height / background.height);
    let width = background.width * scale;
    let height = background.height * scale;
    let x = canvas.width / 2 - width / 2;
    let y = canvas.height / 2 - height / 2;          
    ctx.drawImage(background, x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to figure out a **scale** that you can multiply both the width and the height of the image with, without exceeding the dimensions of the canvas in either direction. This scale can be calculated by dividing the canvas width by the image's width, the canvas height by the image's height and ultimately picking the smaller of both numbers.

Let's take a look at your numbers:

> canvas width: 960 | canvas height: 678 | image width: 768 | image
> height: 768

scaleX = 960 / 768 = 1.25

scaleY = 678 / 768 = 0.8828125

The smaller number is **0.8828125** and thus becomes our final scale.

width = image width * 0.8828125 = 768 * 0.8828125 = 678

height = image height * 0.8828125 = 768 * 0.8828125 = 678

Now we know the target dimensions of **678 x 678**, which as you can see keeps your image's aspect ratio of 1:1.

With these numbers we can also calculate where exactly we need to draw the image to center it inside the canvas.

x = canvas width / 2 - 678  / 2 = 960 / 2 - 678 / 2 = **141**

y = canvas height / 2 - 678  / 2 = 678 / 2 - 678 / 2 = **0**

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw(e) {
  let scale = Math.min(canvas.width / e.target.width, canvas.height / e.target.height);
  let width = e.target.width * scale;
  let height = e.target.height * scale;
  let x = canvas.width / 2 - width / 2;
  let y = canvas.height / 2 - height / 2;

  context.drawImage(e.target, x, y, width, height)
}

var image = new Image();

image.onload = draw;
image.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/400"; // a 400 x 400 image
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=300 style="background-color: #dddddd;"></canvas>
```